# Cannot compile all classes separately in the same package

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have the "Client-server" program which has 3 classes and 1 interface. ([same code but another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662283/java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-connect))

**AddServerIntf.java**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
    double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**AddServerImpl.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {

    public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException {
        return d1 + d2;
    }
}
```

**AddServer.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
            Naming.rebind("AddServer", addServerImpl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**AddClient.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String addServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/AddServer";
            AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(addServerURL);
            System.out.println("The first number is: " + args[1]);
            double d1 = Double.valueOf(args[1]).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("The second number is: " + args[2]);

            double d2 = Double.valueOf(args[2]).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("The sum is: " + addServerIntf.add(d1, d2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

In Eclipse I have the structure like:

[image]

[image]

If I'm trying to compile each `.java` file  using `javac` then getting the errors:

```
    D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddServerIntf.java
    
    D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddServerImpl.java
    AddServerImpl.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {
                                                                      ^
      symbol: class AddServerIntf
    1 error

D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddServer.java
AddServer.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                        AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
                        ^
  symbol:   class AddServerImpl
  location: class AddServer
AddServer.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                        AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class AddServerImpl
  location: class AddServer
2 errors

D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddClient.java
AddClient.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                        AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(Url);
                        ^
  symbol:   class AddServerIntf
  location: class AddClient
AddClient.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                        AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(Url);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class AddServerIntf
  location: class AddClient
2 errors
```

The result is:

[image]

Seems like only interface compiled, but why? I can compile all these classes as one. (if putting the code in one file .java and then compile).

Or I can compile [all the files at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277632/a-java-class-cant-find-an-other-in-the-same-package):

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>cd..

D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder>javac demo\*.java

D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder>
```

And in this case is everything fine.

[image]

But I can't properly understand, why compiler didn't find classes separately. Explain me, please. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Compiling class by class is not required.
In fact you don't execute the command in the correct working directory.
You should not execute `javac` from the `demo` package but rather in the parent dir that contains it.
And it should be fine :

`D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\javac demo\*.java` should be fine

2) As you compile with `javac` (or even as you execute the `java` command), you have to be aware of the classpath value that by default is the current directory where the command is executed.

So this    `D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddServerIntf.java` compiles
but that  `D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo>javac AddServerImpl.java` doesn't compile for the same reason : you execute `javac` from the `demo` package, so it means that only the *content of the demo directory* will be added in the classpath by default. The default classpath you need is a classpath that contains *the demo directory*.
So identical advise : compile your classes from :

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder
```

and not from :

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Shildt\folder\demo
```

Comment: Thank you, David for your detail answer!

Comment: @invzbl3 Glad if it may have helped you. You are very welcome :)

Comment: Also great [additional information](http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html) to my question.